# Empty ListViewGroup is not shown in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I could not find any remarks on MSDN [ListView.Groups Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups.aspx) that empty ListViewGroup will be hidden. Is it by design, or I am missing something? My sample code below will show only "group 2" with item "item1".

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
      Handles MyBase.Load
    '
    Dim gr = New ListViewGroup("group 1")
    ListView1.Groups.Add(gr)
    '
    Dim gr2 = New ListViewGroup("group 2")
    ListView1.Groups.Add(gr2)
    '
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem("item1")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    '
    gr2.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub
```

Updated:
Is there are any way to show ListViewGroup without adding dummy item

For now the only workaround idea I have is to use [collapsible listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330050/collapsible-listview) (Vista and up)

Comment: As far as i know, empty groups are simply not displayed. You could add a blank string item just to display the group.

Comment: Correct. Empty groups do not show up. You have to add items to them first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not possible by Microsoft design.
Look at this discussion on [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/39681a70-d992-4046-ad7e-21a2e33791b1).
Don't be fooled by title. It talks about empty groups.

Comment: That is correct. Looking at the source code for the ListView, all the painting and grouping is done through PInvokes, meaning it's not just a simple matter of overriding the draw method of the ListView. There might be a way you can do it through the use of a little "hack" that I'll post up, but it's not pretty.

Comment: In this case I support the Microsoft design decision. I don't like to open a group and find nothing inside. Better don't show anything.

Answer (score 5):

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) can do exactly this. There is a **ShowEmptyGroups** property that does the trick:

[image: empty group in Better ListView]

There is also a **Better ListView Express**, which is freeware and supports groups as well. It is not a ListView wrapper, but a complete re-implementation of all features, 100% managed and just made... better :-)

Answer (score 4):

this method makes sure the ListViewGroup shows

```
void MakeSureListViewGroupHeaderShows(ListView lv)
{
    foreach (ListViewGroup lvg in lv.Groups)
    {
        if (lvg.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            // add empty list view item
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(string.Empty);
            lvi.Group = lvg;
            lv.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
        else
        {
            // remove our dummy list view item
            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvg.Items)
            {
                if (lvi.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    lvi.Remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hack I'm talking about up above IS NOT RECOMMENDED. However, if you REALLY want empty groups to show up, then you would just delegate the adding code to a separate utility method that checks if the group is empty. If it is, then it adds it to the "default" group (so it at least shows up) until you add an item to it.

```
public static void AddGroup(this ListView lv, ListViewGroup lg)
{
    if (lg.Items.Count > 0 || lv.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(tg => tg.Group == lg))
        lv.Groups.Add(lg);
    else
    {
        var item = lv.Items.Add(lg.Header);
        item.Tag = lg;
    }
}

public static void AddItem(this ListView lv, ListViewItem li, string groupKey) // Could also take ListViewGroup here...
{
    if (lv.Groups[groupKey] == null && lv.Items.ContainsKey(groupKey))
    {
        lv.Groups.Add((ListViewGroup)lv.Items[groupKey].Tag);
        lv.Items.RemoveByKey(groupKey);
    }
    lv.Items.Add(li);
    li.Group = lv.Groups[groupKey];
}

public static void AddItem(this ListView lv, ListViewItem li, ListViewGroup lg)
{
    lv.AddItem(li, lg.Header);
}
```

Another warning, NOT RECOMMENDED. This is quite a bit of overhead, and not really worth the trouble (IMO). But hey, to each their own. This code is completely untested, and just throwing it out there in case you really NEED this to work (which should never be the case, better to look for alternatives). The worst part is that the Group declaration pretty much just resides within the ListItem itself, that way you can just change the group rather easily.

Last warning, NOT RECOMMENDED.

Edit: I've modified the code above to be extension methods on ListView objects, that way you have direct access to the ListView from the methods. Anytime you add a group, you would just call `listView.AddGroup`, adding an item you can use of the `listView.AddItem` methods. This is opposed to `listView.Items.Add` and `listView.Groups.Add` methods. The one thing to keep in mind is that you don't need to assign Items to the Groups, but instead only assign the Groups to the Items. This makes it so you can switch items between groups by changing the reference, instead of having to remove/add references between groups. This also assumes that you've declared the `Header` of the ListItemGroup to be the same as the `Key` (in other words, `new ListItemGroup("HeaderText" /*KEY*/, "HeaderText" /*HEADER*/)`. Otherwise, you'd just have to change the logic within `AddItem` to reference the proper value (which is `Name`, usually).

Answer (score 0):

"I ran into the same issue earlier this year in considering the display of empty groups.  Microsoft, by-design, does not display a group name that is empty of any items.  What you have to do is create/add an empty item or item holding a blank character of text to the group.  When you have actual data item(s) to populate for that group, you must then remember to delete the empty/blank item from that group."

Source:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/39681a70-d992-4046-ad7e-21a2e33791b1